# How does optimistic locking actually enforce re-read/update?

Tags: locking, rdbms, update

My *understanding* of optimistic locking is that it uses a timestamp on each record in a table to determine the "version" of the record, so that when the record is access by multiple processes at the same time, each has a reference to the record's version.

Then, when an update is performed, the timestamp is updated. Before an update is committed, it reads the timestamp on the record a 2nd time. If the timestamp (version) that it has is no longer the timestamp on the record (because it's been updated since the first read), then the process must re-read the entire record and apply the update on the new version of it.

So, if anything I have stated is not correct, please begin by making clarifications for me. But, assuming I'm more or less correct here...

How does this actually manifest itself in a RDBMS? Is this 2nd read/verification enforced in the application logic (the SQL itself) or is it a tuning parameter/configuration that the DBA makes?

I guess I'm wondering where the logic comes from to read the timestamp and perform a 2nd update if the timestamp is stale. So I ask: does the application developer enforce optimistic locking, or is it enforced by the DBA? Either way, how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here are a few examples: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/developing-modifications-that-survive-concurrency/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic technique is quite straightforward.  When you read the record you take a note of the version or timestamp column, e.g.

```
Select FooID
      ,Foo
      ,Bar
      ,TS      -- timestamp
  from Foobar
 where FooID = @FooID
```

When you go to write out the record you filter the write by the timestamp/version so that the write writes nothing if the timestamp/version has changed.  This makes the write atomic, e.g.

```
update Foo
   set Foo = @foo
      ,Bar = @bar
      ,TS = @timestamp  
 where FooID = @FooID
   and ts = @timestamp

select @row_count = @@rowcount  -- specific to t-sql, but this is a system variable
                                -- that holds the number of rows affected by the
if @@rowcount = 0               -- most recent operation.  Other DBMS platforms do
    [deal with outdated record] -- this differently.
```

This allows an application to do the update without holding locks open.  This is necessary
for n-tier systems working through a connection pool, and prevents a class of deadlocks 
that used to be common on two-tier client-server systems.

There is nothing enforced in the database about this.  It's all done explicitly by the application.

Comment: Thanks @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells (+1) - that helps put everything in perspective for me. One quick follow up: I'm sure your code above is just a simple example, but something jumped out at me, and I just want to make sure that I am understanding the core concept correctly: In between the `update` and the `select @rowcount = @@rowcount`, couldn't another process have updated the record? In "real life", would one need to protect against this and put the `updated` and `select` inside a transaction or something to guarantee atomicity? Thanks again!

Comment: @Mara - No.  The @@rowcount is local to the session.  It is a system generated variable that records the number of rows affected by the most recent DML statement.  Note that particular example is specific to T-SQL.  Other DBMS platforms do it slightly differently.

Answer (score 1):

The app doesn't read version column second time. You are just issuing update with extra condition in `where` : `UPDATE table1 set .... WHERE pk_column = some_value and version_column = version_column_value_you_got_in_the_beginning`. Then you check if update was successful(number of rows affected). If it's 0, then you have to re-read data.